# How To display bar graph with error bars?

Tags: python, visualization

I am using the below code to get the bar plot. I want to get the bar plot with error bars displayed.

```
import seaborn as sns

def plot_coefficients(target, coeffs_df, n=10):
    if coeffs_df.shape[0]==0:
        return None # nothing to plot here!
    data = coeffs_df.copy()
    data = data.sort_values(('Coefficient','mean'), ascending=False).head(n)
    g = sns.barplot(
        data=data,
        y='Gene',
        x=('Coefficient','mean'),
        hue='Feature Type',
        hue_order=[
            h for h in [
                'Genomic Variant',
                'Gene Expression',
                'Proteomics',
                'Methylation',
            ] 
        ],
        dodge=False
    )
    g.set(
        xlim=(0,1),
        xlabel='Importance [0,1]',
        ylabel='',
        title=f"Top {target} predictor features"
    )
    return g
```

Coefficient here is a score generated from predictive modelling that ranges from 0 to 1. 2. data here is entire data and I created a mean column. Ideally I wanted to calculate it in [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/) plot rather than creating a mean column separately before.

Comment: I presume you import `seaborn` as `sns`, right?

Comment: @KamilSJaron Yes

Answer (score 1):

I did put forward a comment, it was removed I think the idea is its a full post or zero. The problem proving a negative is tricky.

I don't think its doable within the exact system specified, i.e. a Seaborn bar chart. Again I could be wrong.

If the OP went to a Seaborn dot line formation - that would work `sns.barplot` is changed to `sns.pointplot` but then all the nice colouring disappears. Standard deviation  is one error range if all the values are present: but I think the OP will need to request it (`.sd()` ?? can't remember).

In `matplotlib` there is an error bar method where the coder specifies the error bars and that is `plt.errorbar`. An example from the official docs is [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/errorbar_limits_simple.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-errorbar-limits-simple-py). Thus call a bar chart and then add the error bars onto it.

**Summary** The reasons I don't think its doable in Seaborn:

1. I'm pretty certain Seaborn has no independent errorbar method unlike matplotlib
2. Seaborn can do error bars given the full data set, but those are created automatically for a given method. Maybe there is a "sns.barplot-errorbar" method but I don't know it.

The Seaborn approach does carry the advantage of not having to work out the error bar independently.